# MacOS command line jump to the start of the line

Tags: linux, shell

How to jump to the start/end the line under MacOS command line?

Alt + left/right move cursor word by word. 
I tried Ctrl + left/right, but it inserts D and C respectively. I don't even know what does it mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in emacs mode (default) then ctrl-a for beginning and ctrl-e for end.  http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

add 'set -o vi' to your .bash_profile, then you can use all of the motion commands that vi offers.  so if your typing, hit 'esc' which takes you to command mode, and '0' moves to the beginning, while '$' moves to the end.

http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html